# Why is solidity asking me to restrict state modifier function to view?

Tags: solidity, struct, compiler, solidity-0.8.x

**Version 0.8.7**

Solidity is complaining that several state modifier functions can be restricted to view, such as:

```
function updateStruct(
    uint256 dummyParam
) public onlyOwner {
    DummyStruct memory dummy = dummyStructArray[dummyParam];
    dummy.something = 1;
}
```

Basically, any function that is modifying struct has "function state mutability can be restricted to view" warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view modifier [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/contracts.html?highlight=view#view-functions) states that :

> Functions can be declared view in which case they promise not to
> modify the state.

Additionally, the [rules of assignment](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html?highlight=storage#data-location-and-assignment-behaviour) between storage and memory states :

> Assignments between storage and memory (or from calldata) always
> create an independent copy.

So :

```
function updateStruct(uint256 dummyParam) public onlyOwner {
    // Creates a memory COPY of dummyStructArray[dummyParam]
    DummyStruct memory dummy = dummyStructArray[dummyParam];
    // Modified the memory COPY
    dummy.something = 1;
}
```

You did read the state when accessing `dummyStructArray[dummyParam]`, but you only modifie a memory copy, not the state variable. Therefore, your function fits the view requirements as it does not modify the state.

The `function state mutability can be restricted to view` warning is perfectly valid.

The same behavior can be seen on this code, you can try it on [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Example {
    uint256 public stateVariable = 0;

    function modifiesInMemory() public {
        uint256 memoryCopy = stateVariable;
        memoryCopy = 10;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : Adding simple example as per OP's comment.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
contract Example {
    struct DummyStruct {
        uint256 something;
    }

    DummyStruct[1] public dummyStructArray;


    // Creates a memory copy and operates on it
    // "Assignments between storage and memory (or from calldata) always create an independent copy."
    function modifiesInMemory() public {
        DummyStruct memory memoryCopy = dummyStructArray[0];
        memoryCopy.something = 10;

        // ASSIGN THE MEMORY COPY BACK TO THE STATE VARIABLE
        dummyStructArray[0] = memoryCopy;
    }

    // Creates a local storage reference to the state variable
    // "Assignments from storage to a local storage variable also only assign a reference."
    function modifiedInLocalStorage() public {
         DummyStruct storage localStorageReference = dummyStructArray[0];
         localStorageReference.something = 10;
    }

    // Directly modifies the state variable
    function modifiesInState() public {
        // MODIFIES THE STATE VARIABLE IN PLACE
        dummyStructArray[0].something = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically at some point, it will update the original struct right?

Comment: No. You are updating an independent copy only with this code. You either need to directly modify the state variable, or assign your memory copy to it after your modifications are done.

Comment: Can you please elaborate (or some code reference, link, etc) about assigning modifications on memory copy to original?

Comment: I added an example showing the 3 ways to do it. Memory copy / local storage reference / In place.

Comment: Yep it makes sense now, thanks a lot